# Is it possible to use an overriden function in a Java subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is the problem: I am writing a chess program and I have one super class Piece that has a canMove function that determines whether the destination is a valid location for a chess.

```
public abstract boolean canMove(Piece[][] board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY);
```

And I tried to extend this to other Piece subclasses (Pawn, Rook, etc.) and they all worked well.

However, when I tried to extend this for the King class, I had to use this canMove method for king in another King's function to check whether the situation is checkMate or not.

However, this required me to change King's canMove function into static, and when I did that, it required me to remove the @Override annotation on

```
@Override
public static boolean canMove(Piece[][] board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
```

which caused me to change the name of the canMove of King, but still let me to create a blank canMove function since it is a subclass of a superclass Piece which has an abstract canMove method.

How can I prevent this issue?

Comment: *this required me to change King's canMove function into static* what actually desired the change?

Comment: I think you have more of a design/logic issue than a problem with inheritance.  Each move should just be a function of the state of the board. Try to see if you can make a King's move decision just based on the board.

Comment: why not just make a `isCheckmate` function for the king subclass?

Comment: @nullpointer I don' think it is possible to make an implemented abstract class into static.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Moving function is on the Board class, but each Piece subclass has a boolean that determines whether the destination is a movable position or not.

Comment: @user6792790 I view the decision to move or not should be purely a function of the board and the position of the piece.  I implemented something similar to this for an interview recently and this was my approach (checkers...but used a design that could easily support any 2D board game).

Comment: What is it that makes you want to use the opponent king’s `canMove` method? And aren’t you creating an infinite recursion?? I am not saying your approach is impossible, but my gut feeling is that you could benefit from considering a different one.

Comment: And to answer the question in the title, there is nothing stopping you from calling an overridden method, as in for example `opponentKing.canMove(board, …)`. If you remember to give the object reference (as opposed to the class) before the dot, it will work.